# AQGridView Select Cell

Tags: ios, aqgridview

I create a custom AQGridViewCell like so:

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
{
static NSString * PlainCellIdentifier = @"PlainCellIdentifier";

GridViewCell * cell = (GridViewCell *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlainCellIdentifier"];

if ( cell == nil )
{
    cell = [[GridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(3.333, 3.3336, 100, 100)
                               reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
}
NSString *stringURL = [[featuredStories objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"stringURL: %@", stringURL);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"example0.png"]];
cell.storyID = [[featuredStories objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:0];
return cell;
}
```

and I have added the method when you select the cell like so:

```
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

//I want to NSLog the cell.storyID here
NSLog (@"Selected theArgument=%d\n", index);

}
```

how do I go about accessing the `storyID` within the `cell` in `gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `didSelectItemAtIndex` to the following

```
- (void) gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    //Get the cell at the selected index
    GridViewCell * cell = (GridViewCell *)[grid cellForItemAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"Story Id = %@", cell.storyID);
}
```

Comment: Ok, one quick question. If I `performSegue` in the `didSelect...` but I want to `prepareSegue` with the `storyID` how do I go about getting the `index` from the `prepare` method?

Comment: Never mind, I've decided to scrap using Segues and do it all programmatically.